# Setting global environment variables in docker-compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I am looking for a way to set global environment variables in my `docker-compose.yml` file so that I won't need to duplicate them. What is the best way to do it? As you can see some environment variables are repeated in multiple containers. I don't want to re-write them many times.

```yaml
version: "3.4"

services:
  test-db:
    image: postgres-test:1.4.0
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=password
      - DB_NAME_1=dbname1
      - DB_USER_1=dbuser1
      - DB_PASS_1=dbpass1
      - DB_NAME_2=dbname2
      - DB_USER_2=dbuser2
      - DB_PASS_2=dbpass2
    volumes:
      - test-db-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data 
    restart: on-failure
    ports: 
      - 5432:5432
    networks: 
      - test

  test-key:
    image: key-test:1.4.0
    environment:
      DB_VENDOR: POSTGRES
      DB_ADDR: test-db
      DB_DATABASE: dbname1
      DB_USER: dbuser1
      DB_PASSWORD: dbpass1
      KEY_USER: admin
      KEY_PASSWORD: admin
      #KEY_LOGLEVEL: DEBUG
      KEY_FRONTEND_URL: http://test-key:8080/auth
      KEY_IMPORT: /test-key/test_realm.json
    command: 
      - "-Djboss.as.management.blocking.timeout=3600"
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
    volumes: 
      - $PWD/test_realm.json:/test-key/test_realm.json
    networks: 
      - test
    depends_on:
      - test-db

  test-bus:
    image: bus-test:1.5.0
    environment:
      PYTEST_HOST: test-pytest
      PYTEST_PORT: 8090
      TEST_DB_PW: dbpass2
      TEST_DB_USER: dbuser2
      TEST_DB_NAME: dbname2
      TEST_DB_HOST: test-db
      TEST_KAF_HOST: test-kaf
      TEST_KAF_PORT: 9092 # for a connection inside test-network
      #TEST_SERVER_STATE: PRODUCTION
      TEST_SERVER_STATE: DEVELOPMENT
    ports:
      - 5000:5000
    networks: 
      - test
    depends_on:
      - test-db
      - test-key
```

Comment: https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/  put the shared values in a file

Comment: Thanks Daniel. Is it possible to include more than one .env file?? I am asking because I don't think I can include all the variables in one file because some variables are shared by two containers but not by others.

Comment: https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/#the-env_file-configuration-option you can specify multiple files for each container in the docker-compose.yml.

Comment: @DanielFarrell: The thing is my environment variables have different names even if their values are the same. The variable names cannot be changed. Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

You can define your variables in an env-file named .env beside docker-compose.yml file.

.env

```
dbname1_key=dbname1
dbuser1_key=dbuser1
dbpass1_key=dbpass1
```

Then you can use the variable in docker-compose.yml file

docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3.4"

services:
  test-db:
    image: postgres-test:1.4.0
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=password
      - DB_NAME_1=${dbname1_key}
      - DB_USER_1=${dbuser1_key}
      - DB_PASS_1=${dbpass1_key}
      - DB_NAME_2=dbname2
      - DB_USER_2=dbuser2
      - DB_PASS_2=dbpass2
    volumes:
      - test-db-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data 
    restart: on-failure
    ports: 
      - 5432:5432
    networks: 
      - test

...
```